# Regex to match char after string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to match the first 3 letters that could be a-z followed by a specific character.

For testing I'm using a regex online tester. 
I thought this should work (without success):

```
^[a-z]{0,3}$[z]
```

My test string is abcz.

Hope you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your regex online tester should give you an English-like description of the regexp. Read that **real carefully**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to match a whole string `abcz`, use

```
/^[a-z]{0,3}z$/
            ^^
```

or - if the 3 letters are compulsory:

```
/^[a-z]{3}z$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/peoUsA/1).

The `$[z]` in your pattern attempts to match a `z` after the end of string anchor, which makes the regex fail *always*.

**Details**:

- `^` - string start
- `[a-z]{0,3}`  - 0 to 3 lowercase ASCII letters (**to require 3 letters, remove `0,`**)
- `z` - a `z`
- `$` -  end of string anchor.

Comment: Just in case, if you have time, read more about [limiting quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) and [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) at regular-expressions.info. Also, it is not a good idea to place a single atom into a character class, `[z]` is the same as `z`. People often confuse character classes with grouping constructs, so it is best to keep the pattern as lean as possible.

Answer (score -1):

You've got the *end of line* identifier too early

```
/^[a-z]{0,3}[z]$/m
```

[You can see a working version here](https://regex101.com/r/PQP6Xh/2)

You can do away with the `[]` around `z`. Square brackets are used to define a range or list of characters to match - as you're matching only one they're not needed here.

```
/^[a-z]{0,3}z$/m
```

Comment: @torazaburo Nothing - it's a valid working expression with or without `[]`.